# Symfony VichUploaderBundle: File name could not be generated

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I am using VichUploader to upload files within a symfony project. In configuration i use (copied from documentation):

```
service: vich_uploader.namer_property
options: { property: 'slug'}
```

In my entity i generate the slugs automatically with Gedmo/Sluggable:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"}, updatable=false)
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
protected $slug;
```

But when trying to save the entity i get the following error 500:

> File name could not be generated: property slug is empty.

If i set the property to 'title' it works. Did i forget a configuration parameter or something else to get it working with the Gedmo slug?

Comment: I guess the reason is that both bundles use the `flush` event to operate and are executing in wrong order...

Comment: But are there chances to configure that?

Comment: @Nicki have you found how to do ? I just got the same issue - I changed the namer for  vich_uploader.namer_uniqid as a quick fix but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue at the moment, as a workaround, I've slightly changed the slug getter in the entity class:

```
use Gedmo\Sluggable\Util\Urlizer;

class Event
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    // ...

    public function getSlug()
    {
        if (!$this->slug) {
            return Urlizer::urlize($this->getName());
        }

        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

That did the trick.

Unfortunately, there're a couple of drawbacks:

1. If you ever want to update sluggable behaviour in the annotation to include additional properties, you'll have to update the getter as well.
2. This method lacks a check against the database: if there's already a record in the database with the same name `urlizer` in the getter won't be able to add an increment to the file name, previously saved file may be overwritten! As a workaround, you can add `unique=true` to sluggable properties.

Answer (score 2):

VichUploader listens to the prePersist and preUpdate events, whereas Sluggable listens to the onFlush event. Because prePersist and preUpdate are called before onFlush, it isn't possible to do this purely using configuration.

However, if your file field is nullable, you can work around it by changing your controller code. When you receive the submitted form with the file, remove the file, save the entity, then re-add the file and save the entity again. On the second save, the slug will already be set, so VichUploader will be able to save the file fine.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if ($file = $entity->getFile()) {
        $entity->setFile(null);
    }
    
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    
    if ($file) {
        $entity->setFile($file);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

This only works when adding a new file. If you subsequently change the slug and resave the entity without uploading a new file, the filename is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem uploading a document for which I needed the fileName to be the slug.

I was using Gedmo annotations to generate the slug, however this only triggers on flush and the vichUploader namer is triggered upon persist.

The easiest way for me to get this working was to not use the Gedmo\Sluggable annotation but rather create a prePersist listener on my Document object and use the Cocur\Slugify library.

So here is the code.

My Document Entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DocumentRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\Listeners\DocumentListener"})
 */
class Document
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $fileName;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="document", fileNameProperty="fileName")
     * @var File
     */
    private $documentFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     */
    public function getDocumentFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->documentFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $documentFile
     * @return Document
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setDocumentFile(File $documentFile = null): Document
    {
        $this->documentFile = $documentFile;
        if($documentFile){
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $fileName
     */
    public function setFileName($fileName): void
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }
}
```

And the listener :

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Entity\Document;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;

class DocumentListener
{
    public function prePersist(Document $document, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $slugify = new Slugify();
        if(!empty($document->getDocumentFile())){
            $originalName = pathinfo($document->getDocumentFile()->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $slug = $slugify->slugify($originalName);
            $document->setSlug($slug);
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have not had any problems.

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

By default the doctrine extensions bundle does not attach any listener: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html#activate-the-extensions-you-want

You should configure it to get sluggable working:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
```

Comment: The slug is generated, but it seems that it is generated after VichUploader tries to access it.

Comment: @Nicki and you have the config above in your `config.yml`?

Comment: Not the exact configuration, since i installed Gedmo without the StofBundle. But the listener is configured and slugs are generated.